# How can I tell if I have mini port or micro port on my Android tablet?

Tags: usb

I was given an Android tablet. I want to hook up a keyboard and a mouse. By looking at it, how can I tell if it has a micro port or a mini port?

Answer (score 4):

This one is mini:

[image: mini usb]

and this one is micro:

[image: micro usb]

There's also another new micro version for USB 3.0, which looks like this.  The port is backwards compatible with the previous micro USB cables (you just use half the port and it'll just step down to USB 2.0 speeds).  I'm not sure if any Android devices use the new port as yet.

[image: 3.0 micro b female]  [image: 3.0 micro B male]

Comment: @Compro01 Thanks for the edit. Never heard of that. :)

Comment: It's fairly uncommon as yet.  I've only seem a few devices that use the new micro-B plug, all of them external hard drives.  I don't expect to see them on phones until someone comes up with a new MHL/micro connector.

Comment: @TheDoorkeeper please do not deep-link images; that's frowned upon by many webmasters for good reasons. Instead, use the provided tool to upload them, it also supports uploading from URLs. For details, feel free to visit us in chat. I've fixed that up meanwhile for you ;)